# Why is my Huawei IDEOS X3 (U8510) not appearing in the Device Manager list?

Tags: usb-debugging, huawei-u8500

I have just written my first Hello World app for Android using the Eclipse plug-in. As I understand it, I can run the app from within Eclipse so that it will be automatically downloaded to the phone. I should be able to select whether the emulator or phone should be used.

So far I have not been able to run the app on the phone. There are no connected phones to deploy to. When I look in the Device Manager (Windows 7), there is also nothing there that looks like a phone and nothing in the 'Other devices' group either.

Can anyone suggest what I can do?

Comment: Have you installed the USB drivers for your handset on your PC?

Comment: @chahk - do you mean the drivers which can be downloaded from Huawei? If so then I'm in trouble. The web site seems to be down :-(

Comment: Strange, the site and the download work fine for me: http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=Mzk1MzA=

Answer (score 1):

Alongside installing the correct dirvers, I've found that you may need to also do a bit of manual setup so that your computer can recognise the usb device.

Try this: find the .android folder in your home directory, and replace the adb_usb.ini file with [this one](https://raw.github.com/apkudo/adbusbini/master/adb_usb.ini). this tells your computer to let adb work with a load of different usb devices. You may need to restart ADB via the command line:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and now adb should show you your device

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days back. I discovered that device drivers were not installed correctly on my PC. I installed the device drivers and snapPea.

Hope this helps.